# Word OpenXML remove padding inside table

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am using word open XML.

```
rowCopy.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(0).Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dr["NAME"].ToString()))));
```

The about code is writing name to a cell in the table. But it is creating top and bottom padding inside the cell. How can I remove it. Is it because of the new Paragraph? I am new to word open XML.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Do you want to end up with only the new text in the cell or are you adding the text to existing text? If you only want the new text it's worth removing any existing paragraphs before adding the new one otherwise you could end up with an empty paragraph before your new text (which would look like padding).

Comment: how do I remove the Paragraph. I just need to add the text.

Comment: I've added it as an answer along with some other info @rajmohan.

Comment: @petelids I have edited my question...could you please check

Comment: Could you update your question with your new code please? That looks very much like there is a paragraph before the one you add which the code in my answer should remove for you...

Comment: @petelids is this enough....I had been struggling with this for some days now....all my report have this issue...

Comment: @petelids when the paragraph is removed the content also removed that is the issue...

Comment: cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dr["NAME"].ToString())))); Is there any way to remove Paragraph from this code..

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to remove existing paragraphs before you add your new one. I'm on my phone at the moment but when I get to a computer I'll post a full code sample in the answer.

Comment: @petelids thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an existing Docx file with an empty table in it you might find that there is an empty `Paragraph` in each `Cell`. By using `Append` you are adding your new `Paragraph` after the empty one which causes a space at the top of the cell which looks like padding.

Given that you only require your new text in the `Cell` you can remove any existing `Paragraph` elements *before you add your new `Paragraph`* by calling `RemoveAllChildren` on the `Cell` (or the `Table` if you're confident you don't need any on the `Table`):

```
TableCell cell = body.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
cell.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dr["NAME"].ToString()))));
```

If that isn't the problem then you can control the padding by editing the [`TableCellMargin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablecellmargin%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Something like the following should work:

```
if (cell.TableCellProperties != null && cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin != null)
{
    cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin.BottomMargin = new BottomMargin() { Width = "0" };
    cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin.TopMargin = new TopMargin() { Width = "0" };
}
```

**Edit**

The full code listing would be something like this:

```
static void AddDataToTable(string filename)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        var paras = body.Elements<TableCell>();

        TableCell cell = body.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
        cell.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
        cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dr["NAME"].ToString()))));

        if (cell.TableCellProperties != null && cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin != null)
        {
            cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin.BottomMargin = new BottomMargin() { Width = "0" };
            cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin.TopMargin = new TopMargin() { Width = "0" };
        }

        wordDoc.Close(); // close the template file
    }
}
```

Comment: if (cell.TableCellProperties != null && cell.TableCellProperties.TableCellMargin != null)  always returns null ....what will be the issue?

Comment: In that case it means that no cell properties apply or no cell margins apply. In either case removing any existing paragraphs should fix your issue.

Comment: @rajmohan - did this work for you? Do you need any more info?

Comment: no it didnt work for me....is there any other solution. alternative code for rowCopy.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(0).Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(dr["NAME"].ToString()))));

Comment: @petelidsit didnt work for me....is there any other solution. alternative code for

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work @rajmohan? Did you get an error or did the padding remain in the Word document?

Comment: @petelidsit There is no existing paragraphs in the document. The code which I have is creating paragraph. Is there any way to make it text.

Comment: You're welcome @rajmohan - I've updated the answer with a full method as promised to avoid confusion.